# Detect my accent

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

Your task is to write a program or function that detects accents in UTF-8 input. The catch is that your code must be written entirely in an 8-bit character encoding. The code will output a single integer which is the count of the number of accented letters in the input. Since Unicode is huge, the test input will consist solely of the characters found in [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), stored in the UTF-8 encoding, then treated as ASCII with extended characters (0x09, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x20-0xFF only). The input won't contain any characters below 0x20, except for the three common ones, 0x09 (tab), 0x0A (line feed) & 0x0D (carriage return). It also won't contain 0x7F.

Unicode permits most common accented characters to be represented in multiple ways (only two for the characters in this challenge). `é` could be a pre-composed character: `U+00E9` (`C3 A9` in UTF-8) or a basic letter plus a [combining mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/combining_diacritical_marks/utf8test.htm): `U+0065`+`U+0301` (`65`+`CC 81` in UTF-8). Your code must correctly handle both.

In the following table `*` marks an accented letter. All letters that have two forms will be considered accented, plus `Œ`, `œ`, `Æ` & `æ`. All other characters will be considered as symbols or non-accented letters.

```
1252  Char  Unicode   Char  Unicode
         Bytes           Bytes
   Accented?
-----------------------------------------
80 _  €  3  U+20AC
81 Undefined
82 _  ‚  3  U+201A
83 _  ƒ  2  U+0192
84 _  „  3  U+201E
85 _  …  3  U+2026
86 _  †  3  U+2020
87 _  ‡  3  U+2021
88 _  ˆ  2  U+02C6
89 _  ‰  3  U+2030
8A *  Š  2  U+0160    Š  3  U+0053 U+030C
8B _  ‹  3  U+2039
8C *  Œ  2  U+0152
8D Undefined
8E *  Ž  2  U+017D    Ž  3  U+005A U+030C
8F Undefined
90 Undefined
91 _  ‘  3  U+2018
92 _  ’  3  U+2019
93 _  “  3  U+201C
94 _  ”  3  U+201D
95 _  •  3  U+2022
96 _  –  3  U+2013
97 _  —  3  U+2014
98 _  ˜  2  U+02DC
99 _  ™  3  U+2122
9A *  š  2  U+0161    š  3  U+0073 U+030C
9B _  ›  3  U+203A
9C *  œ  2  U+0153
9D Undefined
9E *  ž  2  U+017E    ž  3  U+007A U+030C
9F *  Ÿ  2  U+0178    Ÿ  3  U+0059 U+0308
A0 _     2  U+00A0
A1 _  ¡  2  U+00A1
A2 _  ¢  2  U+00A2
A3 _  £  2  U+00A3
A4 _  ¤  2  U+00A4
A5 _  ¥  2  U+00A5
A6 _  ¦  2  U+00A6
A7 _  §  2  U+00A7
A8 _  ¨  2  U+00A8
A9 _  ©  2  U+00A9
AA _  ª  2  U+00AA
AB _  «  2  U+00AB
AC _  ¬  2  U+00AC
AD _  2  U+00AD
AE _  ®  2  U+00AE
AF _  ¯  2  U+00AF
B0 _  °  2  U+00B0
B1 _  ±  2  U+00B1
B2 _  ²  2  U+00B2
B3 _  ³  2  U+00B3
B4 _  ´  2  U+00B4
B5 _  µ  2  U+00B5
B6 _  ¶  2  U+00B6
B7 _  ·  2  U+00B7
B8 _  ¸  2  U+00B8
B9 _  ¹  2  U+00B9
BA _  º  2  U+00BA
BB _  »  2  U+00BB
BC _  ¼  2  U+00BC
BD _  ½  2  U+00BD
BE _  ¾  2  U+00BE
BF _  ¿  2  U+00BF
C0 *  À  2  U+00C0    À  3  U+0041 U+0300
C1 *  Á  2  U+00C1    Á  3  U+0041 U+0301
C2 *  Â  2  U+00C2    Â  3  U+0041 U+0302
C3 *  Ã  2  U+00C3    Ã  3  U+0041 U+0303
C4 *  Ä  2  U+00C4    Ä  3  U+0041 U+0308
C5 *  Å  2  U+00C5    Å  3  U+0041 U+030A
C6 *  Æ  2  U+00C6
C7 *  Ç  2  U+00C7    Ç  3  U+0043 U+0327
C8 *  È  2  U+00C8    È  3  U+0045 U+0300
C9 *  É  2  U+00C9    É  3  U+0045 U+0301
CA *  Ê  2  U+00CA    Ê  3  U+0045 U+0302
CB *  Ë  2  U+00CB    Ë  3  U+0045 U+0308
CC *  Ì  2  U+00CC    Ì  3  U+0049 U+0300
CD *  Í  2  U+00CD    Í  3  U+0049 U+0301
CE *  Î  2  U+00CE    Î  3  U+0049 U+0302
CF *  Ï  2  U+00CF    Ï  3  U+0049 U+0308
D0 _  Ð  2  U+00D0
D1 *  Ñ  2  U+00D1    Ñ  3  U+004E U+0303
D2 *  Ò  2  U+00D2    Ò  3  U+004F U+0300
D3 *  Ó  2  U+00D3    Ó  3  U+004F U+0301
D4 *  Ô  2  U+00D4    Ô  3  U+004F U+0302
D5 *  Õ  2  U+00D5    Õ  3  U+004F U+0303
D6 *  Ö  2  U+00D6    Ö  3  U+004F U+0308
D7 _  ×  2  U+00D7
D8 _  Ø  2  U+00D8
D9 *  Ù  2  U+00D9    Ù  3  U+0055 U+0300
DA *  Ú  2  U+00DA    Ú  3  U+0055 U+0301
DB *  Û  2  U+00DB    Û  3  U+0055 U+0302
DC *  Ü  2  U+00DC    Ü  3  U+0055 U+0308
DD *  Ý  2  U+00DD    Ý  3  U+0059 U+0301
DE _  Þ  2  U+00DE
DF _  ß  2  U+00DF
E0 *  à  2  U+00E0    à  3  U+0061 U+0300
E1 *  á  2  U+00E1    á  3  U+0061 U+0301
E2 *  â  2  U+00E2    â  3  U+0061 U+0302
E3 *  ã  2  U+00E3    ã  3  U+0061 U+0303
E4 *  ä  2  U+00E4    ä  3  U+0061 U+0308
E5 *  å  2  U+00E5    å  3  U+0061 U+030A
E6 *  æ  2  U+00E6
E7 *  ç  2  U+00E7    ç  3  U+0063 U+0327
E8 *  è  2  U+00E8    è  3  U+0065 U+0300
E9 *  é  2  U+00E9    é  3  U+0065 U+0301
EA *  ê  2  U+00EA    ê  3  U+0065 U+0302
EB *  ë  2  U+00EB    ë  3  U+0065 U+0308
EC *  ì  2  U+00EC    ì  3  U+0069 U+0300
ED *  í  2  U+00ED    í  3  U+0069 U+0301
EE *  î  2  U+00EE    î  3  U+0069 U+0302
EF *  ï  2  U+00EF    ï  3  U+0069 U+0308
F0 _  ð  2  U+00F0
F1 *  ñ  2  U+00F1    ñ  3  U+006E U+0303
F2 *  ò  2  U+00F2    ò  3  U+006F U+0300
F3 *  ó  2  U+00F3    ó  3  U+006F U+0301
F4 *  ô  2  U+00F4    ô  3  U+006F U+0302
F5 *  õ  2  U+00F5    õ  3  U+006F U+0303
F6 *  ö  2  U+00F6    ö  3  U+006F U+0308
F7 _  ÷  2  U+00F7
F8 _  ø  2  U+00F8
F9 *  ù  2  U+00F9    ù  3  U+0075 U+0300
FA *  ú  2  U+00FA    ú  3  U+0075 U+0301
FB *  û  2  U+00FB    û  3  U+0075 U+0302
FC *  ü  2  U+00FC    ü  3  U+0075 U+0308
FD *  ý  2  U+00FD    ý  3  U+0079 U+0301
FE _  þ  2  U+00FE
FF *  ÿ  2  U+00FF    ÿ  3  U+0079 U+0308
```

- Input will be in any 8-bit encoding which is a super-set of ASCII, i.e. the lower half of the code points will match exactly with ASCII, the upper half (0x80-0xFF) will be used exclusively for multi-byte UTF-8 encoded codepoints, e.g. `“` (`U+201C`) will be treated as both three bytes and three characters by your code: `E2 80 9C`
- Language features or pre-existing libraries that convert character encodings or handle Unicode are forbidden, e.g. JSON (can convert Unicode text to hex), Unicode flag on regex, etc.

Sample output and input:

- `3` `Zoë reads the encyclopædia in a café`
- `0` `Zoe reads the encyclopaedia in a cafe`
- `1` `Zoë` (pre-composed character, 3 codepoints, 4 bytes)
- `1` `Zoë` (base letter + combining mark, 4 codepoints, 5 bytes)
- `2` `déjà vu`

### Scoring

Simple code-golf: lowest number of bytes wins!

This is a re-write as my computer crashed just before posting the first version and I lost all but the first few lines of the challenge. Apologies if I've left anything out!

Comment: 1. At the start of the question you say that the input will be in UTF-8, but later on you say "*any 8-bit encoding which is a super-set of ASCII*". I don't think that the latter is well-specified. There are a potentially unlimited number of ASCII extensions. 2. What about `ñ`, `ø`, etc? I believe that technically neither of those is an accented character, at least in the languages which use them: rather they are full letters of the alphabet. 3. Could you please list the combining characters which we must take into account?

Comment: @PeterTaylor They are accented in English, i.e. they look like an English letter with an accent, therefore they will be considered as accented letters. The input will be _transmitted_ as UTF-8, but mistakenly _interpreted_ by the code as ASCII, since it doesn't know about encodings other than 8-bits.

Comment: Can the input contain accented characters followed by combining accents, such as é̀́̀́̀́̀́? How should they be counted?

Comment: @Pietu1998 Since that combination can't be converted back into Windows-1252 you can safely assume that you won't have to handle it.

Comment: Please provide a full list of all accented characters, using all permitted variations.

Comment: *The remainder of the characters can be determined by their visual appearance*.  I think this is too vague and should be spelled out more explicitly.  Is `Ø` an accented character?  Its tedious, but I you should tabulate this for each character of provide a list of codepoint (or equivalent) ranges

Comment: I count 5 `#` marks in your table - is that right?

Comment: What is the character between `¬` and `®` - it renders as invisible for me on chrome, firefox and safari. (looks like some sort of hyphen/dash when pasted into emacs.  codepoint: 0xAD html: &shy;)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Yes, there are 5 `#`s in the table. These characters are unassigned in Windows-1252. You are correct, the "invisible" character is `&shy;`, `U+00AD`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor It is unclear what is unclear. Would you please clarify what needs clarifying?

Comment: I cast that vote at the same time as I left my comment. But looking at the edited version, I don't understand what all the columns of the table represent (the first two are clear, but what are the rest?); and I still think you need to list the combining characters which must be taken into account.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Do you mean the codepoints of the combining marks?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: Outside of this challenge, a lot of those characters are far from being accents, e.g. æ, œ, ß, ð, þ

Comment: @Fatalize I based whether a character should be considered an accented letter or not based on how likely it is to appear in English text and its appearance. A lot of people wouldn't know the sound values of `ß` (looks like `B` but isn't), `ð` (looks like `d` but isn't), `þ` (looks like `p` or `b` but isn't), etc. (which, although are included in Windows-1252, are not accented in this challenge) but most people would be able to recognise `æ`, `œ` as being almost the same as `ae`, `oe`. æon -> aeon -> (US) eon. I'm not saying that these characters are actually accented.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've updated the table again to include the codepoints. Do you want me to write all the answers as well?

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 46 bytes

```
Count[Characters@#,c_/;RemoveDiacritics@c!=c]&
```

**Explanations:**

`Chatacters` extract every characters in the string. Note that there is a difference between two `Zoë` even if they look the same:

```
Characters["Zoë"]
(* {"Z", "o", "ë"} *)

Characters["Zoë"]
(* {"Z", "o", "e", "̈ ̈"} *)
```

Here, the pattern `c_/;RemoveDiacritics@c!=c` will be matched with those characters that change with diacritics removed. For the first case, only `ë` will match since `ë` becomes `e`. While for the second case, only `̈` will match since it becomes nothing. Whatever case the string is, the counting will be correct.

**Test cases:**

```
f=%; (* assign the function to f. *)

f["Zoë reads the encyclopædia in a café"]
(* 3 *)
f["Zoe reads the encyclopaedia in a cafe"]
(* 0 *)
f["Zoë"]
(* 1 *)
f["Zoë"]
(* 1 *)
f["déjà vu"]
(* 2 *)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is invalid because it uses a built in library/feature of the language.

Comment: @CJDennis I don't really get it. The challange forbiddens libraries that convert character encodings or handle Unicode, however neither "Characters" nor "RemoveDiacritics" convert encodings.

Comment: How does the built-in function work if it isn't just handling Unicode? Your code certainly doesn't initially treat "ë" as two bytes/characters.

Comment: @CJDennis I'm adding some explanations.